# Aloha editor GPL v.2 on a commercial website?

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

Though I found some exhausting answers to Aloha Editor licencing, and even found this reference to another editor on LGPL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960775/tinymce-on-a-commercial-web-page

I didn't found clear answer to whether I can put Aloha JS code to a commercial website, being GPL v.2 licence?

Yes I saw this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640415/does-placing-gpl-licensed-software-on-server-qualify-as-distribution-if-end-us
But question there is eleborate, and so do the answers. Here's a clear direct question about a single thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does placing GPL licensed software on server qualify as 'distribution' if end user never sees it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640415/does-placing-gpl-licensed-software-on-server-qualify-as-distribution-if-end-us)

Comment: I saw this one, but can you please then explain to non-lawyer what answer do you get from these exhausting details about law: yes or no? There's a discussion, but no clear answer to direct question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that with GPL V2 and GPL V3, if your code is running on a server, and you are not distributing your server application itself (i.e. you only have web users interacting with your application, but you don't distribute the application itself) then you are fine.

Read this [page on the AGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-affero-gpl.html) to get a good idea of the difference.  The AGPL exists to have a license that compels distribution of the server code on a non-distributed server based application.

Licensing is complicated, so it is well worth the effort to study all the various licensing options and discussions out there.

Comment: Yes, I read about differences of AGPL, the problem is that's it seems to be not a case with Aloha, as it is shipped as a GPL V2 code. Thanks a lot!